# Server Side rendering with Angular and HapiJS

Tags: angular, hapi.js, server-side-rendering, hapi

I was hoping to get some help on **setting up Server Side Rendering with Angular and [HapiJS](https://hapijs.com/)**. (For my [repo](https://github.com/MaheshSasidharan/server-side-angular/tree/ssrang) here)

The main [github repo](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/hapi-engine/README.md) does not give a complete guide to setup. And all other examples I found (including on [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/universal) are based on **express.js**.

I have created a **[REPO](https://github.com/MaheshSasidharan/server-side-angular/tree/ssrang)** and it works well with *express*, but I am getting issues setting up view engine in `server.hapi.js`.

Instructions for running repo code:

`npm run buildAll` should do.. (More scripts in [*README.md*](https://github.com/MaheshSasidharan/server-side-angular/blob/ssrang/README.md))

to run express, or hapi, just comment the filename `server.hapi.ts` or `server.express.ts` in [webpack.server.config.js](https://github.com/MaheshSasidharan/server-side-angular/blob/ssrang/webpack.server.config.js)